# SOQL Not Recognizing Field?

Tags: apex, soql, compile-error

I have this apex code:

```
//testing code for above
List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
for (MtgPlanner_CRM__Transaction_Property__c lo : [SELECT MtgPlanner_CRM__Borrower_Name__c, MtgPlanner_CRM__Status__c FROM MtgPlanner_CRM__Transaction_Property__c]){
        if (lo.MtgPlanner_CRM__Status__c == 'Closed'){
            Contact c = [SELECT of_Closed_Loans, id FROM Contact WHERE id = lo.MtgPlanner_CRM__Borrower_Name__c];
            if (!String.isBlank(c.of_Closed_Loans){
                c.of_Closed_Loans= Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(c.of_Closed_Loans) + 1); 
            } else {
                c.of_Closed_Loans= 1;
            }
            contacts.add(c);
        }
    }
update contacts
```

In workbench's Apex Execute,

> COMPILE ERROR: Unexpected token 'lo.MtgPlanner_CRM__Borrower_Name__c'.
>   LINE: 5 COLUMN: 77

It seems like it is not recognizing this part of the SOQL statement:

```
WHERE id = lo.MtgPlanner_CRM__Borrower_Name__c]
```

However, 
`System.debug(lo.MtgPlanner_CRM__Borrower_Name__c)` works fine.

I just want to get the Contacts that have id's equal to the MtgPlanner_CRM__Transaction_Property__c object's MtgPlanner_CRM__Borrower_Name__c field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a preceding colon when using bind variables:

**Correct**

```
WHERE Field__c = :value
```

**Incorrect**

```
WHERE Field__c = value
```

See also: [Using Apex Variables in SOQL and SOSL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm) (emphasis mine):

> SOQL and SOSL statements in Apex can reference Apex code variables and expressions **if they’re preceded by a colon (:)**. This use of a local code variable within a SOQL or SOSL statement is called a bind. The Apex parser first evaluates the local variable in code context before executing the SOQL or SOSL statement.